# Access to DOM elements imported from another file

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

Hello to all the Community!

As it is my first post on this site, which I use intensively, I want first to warmly thank all contributors who provide such a tremendous help!

And, as I did not find anything about me personal problem, here it is, simplified as much as I could.

For maintenance and clarity reasons, the side menu of my pages is in an external file, called let’s say “menu.html”. Its content is quite simple (I simplify and only show its body):

```
<body>
    <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        …
    </ul>
</body>
```

Now, in the pages of the site, there is a simple line before the content of my page:

```
<aside id=”Menu”></aside>
```

Here is thus the skeleton of my pages body:

```
<body>
    <aside id=”Menu”></aside>
    <main>
        … My page content
    </main>
</body>
```

In the main JavaScript function called by the pages, I have the standard instruction:

```
$("#Menu").load("menu.html");
```

and the menu is displayed accordingly. No problem. (Purists will tell me that such a programming induces up and down exchanges, but this is not the purpose of this post.)

If I want to hide the menu with $("#Menu").hide(), it works fine and the menu is hidden. **BUT if I want to hide elements of the menu, it does not work.** In another words:

```
$("#Menu").hide() works fine,
$("#Menu ul").hide() does NOT work.
```

In conclusion, it seems that, although the DOM correctly integrates all items from the menu (I use Dreamweaver and I can check in the DOM panel that everything is actually present), jQuery cannot access to them.

My purpose is of course more complex (change the colours of the menu, depending on the page own colours), but I have simplified it as much as I could.

Thank you in advance for your remarks on this curious behaviour.

Comment: You need to put the hide calls in the callback of `load()`, so that they are executed *after* the async request has completed and added the content to the DOM. Check the 'complete' argument in the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/load/). There is also an example showing its usage further down the page

Comment: As an aside, given this statement: *I use Dreamweaver and I can check in the DOM panel that everything is actually present* - be very wary testing within your IDE, especially one as outdated as Dreamweaver. Always test directly in the browser itself where possible.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I'm sorry about your dreamweaver issues, seriously consider [IntelliJ ultimate](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/). It's standard in Fortune 500's and I just got all the guys I work with this start up to make the switch from VS code. Anyway, all event listeners on the Dom will only attach to elements available on execution. Thus when a new html block loads into DOM its associated JS must THEN be run. React JS development is really a new paradise, but I know how the real word works so just take that suggestion for what it is.

Comment: Also please note the case of replacing a menu with the same id.. Multiple event listeners can `stack` on top of another even if their refs are gone. It all depends on how you implement.

Comment: Oh, and welcome to stack overflow!

Comment: A thousand thanks, Rory and Tyler, for your extraordinarily fast answers, which solve indeed my problem. I thought that, once the menu was loaded, I could access to it in the JavaScript functions called AFTER the integration of the menu.

One word about Dreamweaver: it is obviously not a good programme and I am very surprised that Adobe does not put more efforts to update it, but I have a subscription to their Creative Suite. But, of course, I test my programmes inline and the issue I faced was after inline tests.

Last, but not least: thank you, Tyler for, your warm welcome address!